# Rewriting taxonomy URL from ID to slug

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, seo, taxonomy

I'm trying to rewrite the URL for my wordpress website to be more user and SEO friendly. But I'm not sure about the rewrite rule I should add to the .htaccess file.

Basically, I want to rewrite this: `https://www.mywebsite.com/city/london/?cat_id=123`
to: `https://www.mywebsite.com/london/mobile-phones`

Both "london" and "mobile-phones" are taxonomies here.

Comment: You need to do this in WordPress, not .htaccess.

Comment: Hmm and how should I do that? If you have the Permalink options in mind, that does nothing since these are custom taxonomies.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a 301 redirection as:

```
redirect 301 /city/london/  https://www.mywebsite.com/london/
```

since in the second URL, there is no 'city' slug.

Also please try this method for the URL rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^london/(.*)/ wp-content/themes/mytheme/single-mycategory.php?cat_id=$1
```

Then in that single-mycategory.php file, you can fetch the cat_id and display the data associated with that category.